# how to remove data object from reponse coming from laravel fractol library?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am getting data as an object in response from laravel fractal library by default for all APIs.

I don't want data instead I want some custom name instead of data but I am not able to do that.

How to customize the code from the fractal library to get the item instead of data.

Answer (score 0):

Create `DataSerializer` Class:

```
namespace App\{Your Project Name}\Serializers;

use League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer;

class DataSerializer extends ArraySerializer
{
    public function collection($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        if ($resourceKey) {
            return [$resourceKey => $data];
        }

        return $data;
    }
    public function item($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        if ($resourceKey) {
            return [$resourceKey => $data];
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Add `setResponseData` function in Base Controller:

```
public function setResponseData($default=true, $data, $transformer, $includes = null){

    if($default){
        $resource = fractal($data, $transformer);

        if($includes){
            $resource->parseIncludes($includes);
        }
        return $resource;
    }

    $resource = null;
    if($data instanceof LengthAwarePaginator){
        $dataCollection = $data->getCollection();
        $resource = new Collection($dataCollection, $transformer, 'data');
        $resource->setPaginator(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($data));
    } elseif($data instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection){
        $resource = new Collection($data, $transformer, 'data');
    } elseif($data instanceof Model){
        $resource = new Item($data, $transformer, 'data');
    } else{
        return [];
    }

    $manager = new Manager();
    $manager->setSerializer(new DataSerializer());

    if($includes){
        $manager->parseIncludes($includes);
    }

    $content = [];
    if($resource){
        $content = $manager->createData($resource)->toArray();
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Call `setResponseData` function from your Derived Controller:

```
$response = $this->setResponseData(false, $data, new YourTransformer(), ['include-1']);
```

Comment: Thanks, bro for the reply, will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Sure, one more thing Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.6 version.